# Typescript adding types from library to global

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a ts library that defines some types like this:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
        SafePromise: any;
    }
}
```

What do I need to do so when I import this library, the following types would be recognized with the need to declare them 1 by 1.

I tried adding my library's node_modules path to the typesRoot with no success

Comment: are you outputting your .d.ts files with your library?

Comment: Yes, the .d.ts files looks exactly like the one I posted